# magento 1 use old cdn instead of new one

Tags: cdn

I have this in my settings:
[image]

But site still using old path despite I cleared cache
[image]

Comment: check at a lower level in the configuration. This looks like the global config. Check at website or store view level.

Comment: I checked, store views use global settings

Comment: websites also? Maybe the cache is not where it should be. Try disabling it. At least you eliminate the cache as being a problem.

Comment: I disable the cache on magento and cleared var/cache multiple times, I have no clue why  it still use old source